# Selecting rows that are not defined

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How to select rows which are not defined? Like row 2 have undefined day 3 and row 3 have undefined day 1. I want them to be 0 in result set.

```
+----+-----+-------+
| id | day | count |
+----+-----+-------+
|  1 |   1 |   262 |
|  1 |   2 |   685 |
|  1 |   3 |   984 |
|  2 |   1 |   692 |
|  2 |   2 |   962 |
|  3 |   2 |   355 |
|  3 |   3 |   741 |
+----+-----+-------+
```

EDIT:
I want select `count` from days 1, 2 and 3 (not whole table) and display 0 on undefined day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- We can get all unique `id` values in a Derived Table.
- For `day`, you seem to want only 1,2 and 3 only. So we can directly consider these values only using `UNION ALL`.
- `CROSS JOIN` between them to get all possible combinations.
- `LEFT JOIN` from `all_combinations` table to the main table on `id` and `day`.
- We can use `Coalesce()` function to consider 0 value for count, for the cases where there is no matching row in the main table

Try the following:

```
SELECT all_combinations.id, 
       all_combinations.day, 
       COALESCE(t.count, 0) AS count 
FROM 
(
  SELECT ids.id, days.day 
  FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM your_table) AS ids 
  CROSS JOIN 
  (SELECT 1 AS day UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) AS days
) AS all_combinations 
LEFT JOIN your_table AS t
  ON t.id = all_combinations.id AND 
     t.day = all_combinations.day
```

**Result:**

```
| id  | day | count |
| --- | --- | ----- |
| 1   | 1   | 262   |
| 2   | 1   | 692   |
| 3   | 1   | 0     |
| 1   | 2   | 685   |
| 2   | 2   | 962   |
| 3   | 2   | 355   |
| 1   | 3   | 984   |
| 2   | 3   | 0     |
| 3   | 3   | 741   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v1WzMuLfgzbXC4Y8XB9bsT/1)

Comment: Selects undefined row, but all counts are 0.